# Rails need to pass field to model before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Employees, Contacts and Users.  When a new Contact or Employee is created, their respective model creates a new User.  These are the relations:

```
  Contact belongs_to :user
  Employee belongs_to :user  
  User has_one :contact 
  User has_one :employee
```

Right now I've got an email field in all 3 tables.  But, I'd like to remove the email field from the Contact and Employee and only use the User.email.

Currently the Contact Model code is this:

```
before_create :create_user

protected
def create_user
  self.user = User.create({ :email => self.email, :password => 'password' })
  return user.save
end
```

The Contact form has this:

```
            <%= f.input :email %>
```

How can I get the email into the Contact form and pass it to the Contact controller to put into the new User record?

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

I tried this, but it didn't work:

Contact Form:

```
  <%= text_field_tag :email %>
```

Contact Controller:

```
  protected
  def create_user
    self.user = User.create({ :email => params[:email], :password => '123456' })
    return user.save
  end
```

UPDATE 2

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

Contact Form:

```
     <%= params[:email] = email_field_tag 'email'%>
```

Contact Controller:

```
  before_create :create_user

protected
def create_user
  self.user = User.create({ :email => params[:email], :password => '123456' })
  return user.save
end
```

Comment: Is the model code displayed for Contact? If so, it seems a bit odd to me that the parent would be created as a before_filter of the child, rather than the child being created as an after_filter of the parent. Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: I have two forms to add users = New Contact or New Employee.  When you add a person to either one, a new User is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `text_field_tag` helper method to create the input field in the view, but that sounds like abusing the model.  If your form represents the 'Contact' model, why not leave the `email` attribute in `Contact` and remove it from `User`?  Then, to keep things convenient, you can add the following to `User` (note: untested code):

```
def email
    contact.email
end

def email= email_addr
    contact.mail = email_addr
end
```

Comment: Not sure it would work to keep the email in Contact.  I'm using Devise for security/logon and the user enters their email, password to sign-in.  I also have an Employee table that is setup the same way as the Contact table.  So, I'd like to keep the email in the User table.

Comment: I think your models are mixed up.  You should update your question to explain how the Employee model factors into all of this.

Comment: easier than those email setter and getter methods would be simple delegation. http://sapnaprajapatiblog.blogspot.de/2010/05/delegation-with-rails.html Additionally he might want autosave.